# Make Next And Prev buttons without using any query parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to display calender of three months with Next button to display next 3 months and prev button to display previous 3 months.My model contain a property called `BeginDate` that its value is the date of first day of the current 3 month.When I click the next button I add three month to the `BeginDate` and bind it to hidden field in my view. and return the model with new `BeginDate` but the value of hidden field not changed.

My Model

```
public class MyModel
{
   public DateTime BeginDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new MyModel());
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    model.BeginDate = model.BeginDate.AddMonths(3);           
    return View(model);
}
```

**Note I want to do that without put any parameter in my url**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove it from the model state if you intend to modify its value in the POST action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("CurrentBegin");
    model.CurrentBegin = DateTime.Parse(Request.Form["CurrentBegin"]).AddMonths(3);           
    return Index(model);
}
```

The reason for this is because HTML helpers such as TextBoxFor, HiddenFor, ... will first look at the request if there is a corresponding value and after that in the model. Because you are in the POST action, there's the old `CurrentBegin` value in the POST body and that's what will be used by the hidden helper, not the one you are putting in the model. That's by design and that's how helpers work. If you want to use the value of the model and ignore the POSTed value you need to remove it from the model state as shown.

Comment: Why is "Html.DisplayFor" for example not looking into the request before?

Comment: @Peter Gfader, because the [default display template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) for a string property looks like this: `@Html.Encode(ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)` which basically uses the value of the model and not modelstate or request.